# I want to search text in other sheet and get value from column of found row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuggling in getting a formula for the following:

I have Sheet1 and Sheet2

In Sheet1 I want to check if for each value in column A, there is matching text on Sheet2 column A. I got the formula for that:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2;Sheet2!$A:$A;0);"Yes");"No")
```

This works fine and gives me back a yes or no.

What I need now is, if the value is true (Yes), I need to get the text in column B on Sheet 2.

Sheet1
[image]

Sheet2
[image]

So what I want to do in short is, I first want to check if John is also on sheet 2, and if yes, I want to check if his age is same in both sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using IFERROR + VLookup. This will return the value in Column B if match is found, otherwise returns "No".

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,0),"No")

Answer (score 0):

On sheet1 cell C2 (I assume you have header).

```
=If(B2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,false),-1),"Yes","No")
```

Meaning I use Vlookup, and if that fails to find "John" it will return -1, which will fail the if and return "No".

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,0))=B1,"Equal","Not Equal")
```